# Online Database instead of wamp

Tags: android, wamp

Ok so I created an Android app with use of WAMP. Is there any way to put it online in a cloud or website or do I have to rent a server? I have been looking all over the place for that but I still did not manage to answer that question.

Can you guys help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your current WAMP Setup?  If it's on your local workstation then you will need to either configure that workstation to be publicly accessible or you will need to put it on a server that is publicly accessible.  A cloud and a website are both run on servers, so asking if you can put it on one OR if you have to rent a server is not mutually exclusive.  If you can't find one for free, you will need to pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little puzzled by your question. You have an app and you need a server for it? Yes, you *can* rent a server, or buy one, but I wouldn't suggest that. The most popular way to host databases nowadays is using Cloud Computing. You should probably look into [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/). Many people use EC2.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, but yes that what I was looking for, but isn't there any website like Amazon AWS free? for small DB's?

Comment: @user3445091 If it's really small, then sure there are. You'll have to Google "free cloud hosting" and find out which you like best. I think GoDaddy might have a free plan, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually, AWS has a free trial kind of thing. GoGrid and Azure too. Although it's only for about a month :/. Truth is - nothing is free and you'll have to pay.